# Livewire: Prevent captcha image to refresh when typing

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I've made contact form with livewire and stumbled little problem.

I have captcha image which is refreshing everytime I type something in form. Is there way to prevent some part or whole page not to refresh when typing?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the image in a div and use wire:ignore on the parent div